# What word means the state of not only obviously appearing to have quality Q, but also, actually having quality Q?

Tags: meaning, semantics, diction

In English how can I most succinctly convey the state of some item P where it should not only obviously appear to have quality Q, but should also actually have quality Q?

Or (dropping the subjunctive if it's easier): What word means the state of not only obviously appearing to have quality Q, but also, actually having quality Q?

If a door "appears" locked, it might be unlocked. Even if a door "readily appears" locked, it could still be locked. How can I say it not only appears locked but actually is locked, without repeating myself?

For example suppose I'm instructing an employee of my security company on how to properly setup a security system at a customer's house.

How can I most briefly describe the condition that a house will be in after my employee should render it into a state where not only does it have a security system, but also, the fact that it has a security system should now be obvious to anyone from the street?

Comment: “The door is locked” is absolute, but leaves appearances out of it.  But your word “obviously” adds the appearance part:  “The door is obviously locked”

Comment: The house was secure, and obviously so. There are many ways to write this.

Comment: @Jim Although “obviously locked” can work, “obviously” as an intensifier can miss the visual element of *seen to be locked*. In the OP’s context, they may need something more explicit - such as Xanne’s approach of moving “obviously” to a separate clause.

Comment: @Lawrence -  I disagree.  What else could *obviously* mean?

Comment: @Jim In the OP’s context, I can imagine something like “I locked it myself, so it’s obviously locked”, which is equivalent to “... so *of course* it’s locked”. This doesn’t convey the OP’s intent that it needs to also appear to be locked.

Comment: visibly or self-evidently or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The house was manifestly equipped with a security system.

From [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/manifestly):

> **manifestly** [adverb]
>
> In a way that is clear or obvious to the eye or mind.
>
> - *We have manifestly failed to exercise good judgment.*

Comment: Ah this is perfect! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> How can I say it not only appears locked but actually is locked, without repeating myself?

You concern about repeating yourself is unjustified: "Not only does it look "X", but it ***is*** "X" is very common and perfectly acceptable.

"Not only does it look expensive/hot/dangerous, but it ***is*** expensive/hot/dangerous.

You can also say: "Not only does it look "X", but it is."

Formally, you can use something like:

"It looks expensive/hot/dangerous and its appearance does not lie." (To lie = to be untruthful)